# Adding a character at the beginning of a string if it does not exist using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I have a string which I apply some LINQ methods. After applying a Replace, I would like to add a '/' character at the beginning of the resulting string if and only if it does not exists yet.

For example:

```
string myString = "this is a test";
string newString = myString.Replace(" " , string.Empty).AddCharacterAtBeginingIfItDoesNotExists('/');
```

So the resulting newString should be:

> "/thisisatest"

If character '/' already exists, it is not needed to add it. For example:

```
string myString = "/this is a test";
string newString = myString.Replace(" " , string.Empty).AddCharacterAtBeginingIfItDoesNotExists('/');
```

So the resulting newString should be:

> "/thisisatest"

Comment: Just use `Regex.Replace()`: `Regex.Replace(mystring.Replace(" ", String.Empty), "^(?=[^/])", "/")` (Or an immediate lambda: `((Func<string,string>)((string s) => s.StartsWith('/') ? s : "/"+s)).Invoke("/test this".Replace(" ", string.Empty))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.StartsWith`:

```
public static string AddStringAtBeginningIfItDoesNotExist(this string text, string prepend)
{
    if (text == null) return prepend;
    if (prepend == null) prepend = "";
    return text.StartsWith(prepend) ? text : prepend + text;
}
```

(allowed string instead of char to be more useful)